# How to refer to a checkbox in access navigation form through vba (Detail_Format) in report

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to hide details section in a report if checkbox in navigation form is not checked.

It's not working somehow, please tell me what am I doing wrong.

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
If Forms!DASHBOARD!NavigationSubform.Form!rptMain.chkWaBox.Value = True Then
Detail.Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your details section set to visible in design view? If it is, your code will not hide it. Your code only makes it visible if it's hidden.

When using boolean values like this, I like to make the assignment directly, so it doesn't matter what the state of the object is in design, it always gets handled correctly at runtime:

```
Private Sub Detail_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    Detail.Visible = Forms!DASHBOARD!NavigationSubform.Form!rptMain.chkWaBox.Value
End Sub
```